# Button positioning using Layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

After many hours I can't fix button on the bottom of activity. Either is invisible or at the top. I tried also without relative layout, I tried adding another linear layout, but I still don't know how set this button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".News" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/news" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/newsbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Chiudi" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it currently looks like?  It's possible your button is getting pushed off the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/news" />

    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
            android:id="@+id/newsbutton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Chiudi" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ImageView will overlap with WebView.

Comment: Please add >> android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"

Comment: Nice answer! help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a warning in Legacy Android Layout Editor, that either RelativeLayout or LinearLayout is useless. That should be a hint for you. Pay attention to warnings, they're helpful in most of the times.

Indeed, you can **get rid of LinearLayout**.

So, the solution is:

1. **Remove LinearLayout.**
2. **Add `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"` to the  WebView.**
3. **Add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the Button.**
4. Add `android:contentDescription` to ImageView.
5. Use @string instead of hardcoded strings.

Optional steps are not bolded, they will remove warnings.

Whole working code, tested under Android 4.1.2:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="TODO: DESCRIPTION"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" />


<Button
        android:id="@+id/newsbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Chiudi" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. On android 2.1 app crashed

Answer (score 0):

copy paste the following in your button component ;)

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="147dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginleft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
```

play only with the numbers and Im sure ull get the hang of it :)

Answer (score -1):

Just add android:layout_below="@id/webView1" in your button.

If you would use LinearLayout, you could set the Widget that should fill the empty space like this: layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1". This should do the job too.

Comment: Using your tag I don't see the button. Same problem. Thanks.